# Laravel - how to abstract underlying logic through exposing a generic Class

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to build a good building block for my application to avoid vendor locking. It's Laravel 5.4, and here is the scenario I need help with:

I want to implement SMS sending but I don't want to be locked to a single vendor.

So conceptually in code, I would do something like this:

```
use App/SMS;

// controller

public function send_sms() 
{
    SMS::send('Thanks for saving', $number);
}
```

However SMS is just an abstraction, which would be calling a real implementation's class functions, which I may have many of, and switch out in a config file for example.

```
class SMSGlobal implements SMSProvider 
{
    public function send($msg, $to)
    {
        // Whatever the logic here is for SMSGlobal to send an SMS.
    }
}

class Nexmo implements SMSProvider 
{
    public function send($msg, $to)
    {
        // Whatever the logic here is for Nexmo to send an SMS.
    }
}


// Somewhere else, I would set SMS to a particular provider (in config)?

'SMSProvider' => 'SMSGlobal'
```

I hope this makes sense. I'm just not sure how to implement this type of thing - conceptually it makes sense (in my head).

I would have MANY of these abstractions, so the system is not vendor locked.

It would be similar to the way Cache works, where in config you set 'redis' and then calling Cache::get() uses the redis provider but as a programmer there is no difference whether the backend is database/file or redis.

Cheers!

FYI - Also asked here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/abstracting-underlying-logic

Not sure of the size of the community there though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing creating and passing around an [interface](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) which is bound to implementing classes.  In Laravel you can bind an interface with implementing classes as described in the docs on the [service container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container).